# Berlin to Szczecin with 49 euros ticket

Tags: germany, public-transport, poland, deutsche-bahn, deutschlandticket

I have read that Szczecin Hbf is not covered with the 49 euros ticket. This is the route I wanted to take from Berlin:

Berlin -> Angermunde (in germany)

Angermunde -> Szczecin Glowny (bus RB66)

Is Szczecin Glowny also not covered?

If I buy a day ticket for Szczecin, can I use it on this bus ride as well?

Can I buy a supplementary ticket via the bus driver? At what point do I need to buy an additional ticket? It seems to be a 1+ hour bus ride without any stops.

How much would it cost me?

Alternative Route:

RE4 from Grabow (Germany) -> Szczecin Gumience -> Szczecin Glowny

Comment: The d-ticket surely isn't valid internationally

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Generally no, but [it's valid on some German bus and train lines in The Netherlands near the border](https://www.nrz.de/region/niederrhein/verkehr-wo-das-deutschlandticket-in-den-niederlanden-gilt-id238318141.html), so it's reasonable to check if this is also true for Poland.

Comment: See: [Günstig zwischen polnischen und deutschen Grenzbahnhöfen fahren](https://www.bahn.de/angebot/regio/berlin-brandenburg/grenzuebergangsfahrkarten-polen-deutschland)

Answer (score 2):

The complete validity is shown [in this table at bahn.de](https://www.bahn.de/faq/deutschlandticket-verkehrsmittel-deutschland).  The Deutschlandticket is valid on some connections outside Germany.  Typically, those are connections to the first station immediately at the border.  In Poland, it's valid on:

- Ahlbeck Grenze – Świnoujście Centrum
- Görlitz – Zgorzelec
- Hirschfelde – Krzewina Zgorzelecka – Hagenwerder

So you can reach Świnoujście, Zgorzelec, and Krzewina Zgorzelecka with the Deutschlandticket, the same is not true for Szczecin.

Fun fact: Krzewina Zgorzelecka is in Poland, but serves the German village of Ostritz.  The only passenger trains lead to Germany — it's not possible to travel directly by train from Krzewenia Zgorzelecka to other parts of Poland, without passing through Germany first.  See [Openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=51.015694&mlon=14.939722&zoom=15#map=14/51.0158/14.9429):

[image: Krzewina Zgorzelecka]

See [this article in alles-lausitz](https://www.alles-lausitz.de/ostritzer-bahnhofstation-auf-polnischem-territorium.html) for more information about how the train station in Ostritz ended up in Poland as a consequence of history.

Comment: What if I take the Angermunde -> Szczecin Glowny (bus RB66)? At what point do I need to buy an additional ticket? It seems to be a 1+ hour bus ride without any stops.

Comment: @x89 I don't know.

Comment: @x89: since there are no stops, there is no way to calculate a partial fare. Chances are the Deutschlandticket doesn't help here and you have to pay full price.